# How does when_any work?

Tags: windows-8, c++-cx, ppl

I have a `std::vector< concurrency::task<void> >` with a list of tasks that may or may not load in order.  I came across the `concurrency::when_any` call, but don't know enough information about how to use it.

I came across [this microsoft sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Asynchronous-08009a0d/sourcecode?fileId=62668&pathId=1464804857) that uses the call (ScenarioInput1.xaml.cpp:100), but I don't understand the pair parameter, and how to adapt that to my return values.

**Edit:** What I'm trying to do:

```
struct TaskInfo {
  unsigned int                    uniqueId;
  concurrency::task<unsigned int> task;
};
typedef std::vector< TaskInfo > TaskList;
typedef std::vector< unsigned int > TaskReturns;


// Somewhere inside a class, tasks and finished are member variable.
TaskList tasks;
bool finished = false;

// Inside a member function of the same class as above
// Populate the tasks

concurrency::when_any( tasks.begin(), tasks.end() ).then([this](std::vector<unsigned int> ids){
  for( std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator list=ids.begin; list != ids.end(); ++ids ) {
    // a mutex lock would happen here
    for( TaskList::iterator allTasks = tasks.begin(); allTasks != tasks.end(); ++allTasks ) {
      if ( *list == allTasks->uniqueId ) { tasks.erase( allTasks ); break; }
    }
    // mutex unlock
    if ( tasks.size() == 0 ) { finished = true; break }
  }
}

// In another member function
if ( finished ) doOtherThings();
```

If what I'm trying to do is not as well thought out or not as efficient, please let me know.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh749973.aspx

Comment: I'm confused, I don't see any usage of `when_any()` in the file you referenced.

Comment: Sorry, it seems the download package and the online source code are slightly different.

Comment: Ah, sorted it out, thanks to @hans-passant - the parameter in when_any( ... ).then( <here> ) should be a `std::pair< returnType, size_t indexOfTask>`.  @hans-passant, please add an answer and I will mark it.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Looks to me you can write a much better answer than I could.  So go ahead and post one and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Well, even if you just post the link, I'd rather mark someone elses answer.  I only came to the correct answer because of the link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant provided [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh749973.aspx) which told me that `when_any( ... ).then([]( <params> )` requires  to be of the type `std::pair<returnType, size_t index>`.

Answer (score 4):

It's the "choice" combination for tasks. You have a continuation (then), a join (when_all) and choice (when_any).  [The docs say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh749973.aspx) ...

> Creates a task that will complete successfully when any of the tasks
>   supplied as arguments completes successfully.

See the [task class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh750113.aspx) and [Asynchronous programming in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780559.aspx) for more details.  [More discussion and examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781020.aspx).

Take for example:

```c
task<string> tasks[] = {t1, t2, t3};
auto taskResult =  when_all (begin(tasks), end(tasks))
    .then([](std::vector<string> results) {
```

... is equivalent to ...

```c
(t1 && t2 && t3).then
```

Whereas ...

```c
task<string> tasks[] = {t1, t2, t3};
auto taskResult = when_any (begin(tasks), end(tasks))
    .then([](string result) {
```

... is equivalent to ...

```c
(t1 || t2 || t3).then
```

Comment: After doing some more reading, it looks like rather than (from your example) `string result` as the when_any parameter for the .then action, it should be  `std::pair<string, size_t> result`.  At least I wasn't the only confused one :)